# Sql server - Inner Join syntax with two joins

Tags: sql-server, syntax, inner-join

I've noticed one of our programmers wrote this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A A
  INNER JOIN Table_B B
    INNER JOIN Table_C C
      ON C.Id = B.Id
        ON B.Id = A.Id
```

I didn't expect this to work but it does return results from our database.

Does this work the same as the normal join syntax? I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: Yes this is similar to the normal joins. These are explained in the book ''SQL Server Bible"

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The way I usually recommend people think about it is as if `JOIN` acts the same as an opening bracket `(` and `ON` acts the same as a closing bracket `)`. Then the normal rules you're used to for bracket matching tell you *which* `ON` clause relates to *which* `JOIN`, and gives you some context for determining which table names/aliases are in scope.

So this query effectively joins table `B` to table `C`, then joins `A` to *that* combined result.

I'd normally recommend against it when purely using `INNER JOIN`s - you can rearrange the tables easily so that you follow the more "normal" `JOIN`/`ON`/`JOIN`/`ON` pattern. You get the same logical result from this query<sup>1</sup>:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_B B
INNER JOIN Table_C C
  ON C.Id = B.Id
INNER JOIN  Table_A A
  ON B.Id = A.Id
```

---

Note that this *is* covered by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if you've read it carefully:

> ```
> <table_source> ::=   
> {  
>     table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
>         [ <tablesample_clause> ]   
>         [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
>     ...
>     | <joined_table>
>     ...
> ```

And

> ```
> <joined_table> ::=   
> {  
>     <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>
>     ...
> ```

So, in a `<joined_table>`, what goes on the left of the `<join_type>`? Any `<table_source>`. And what goes on the right of the `<join_type>`? Any `<table_source>`. And either or both of those can, themselves, in fact be a `<joined_table>`.

The "normal" form you refer to in your question is what falls out if we only allow ourselves to use a `<joined_table>` in the left-hand position of another `<joined_table>`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Although if you're relying on the column *order* rather than column *names*, you'll get columns in a different order due to using `SELECT *`. But you shouldn't rely on column orders.

Comment: +1 for recommending against the syntax in OP's question. Readability is paramount to any collaborative software project. Also, I've had to write quite a few dozen+ table join statements before, so that syntax will not scale (unless you like horizontal scrollbars).